# Does finding neighbors in Bitcoin consider locality and hop count?

Tags: protocol, network, peer-discovery, p2p

When the list of neighbors is being gathered by a new nodes in the network, does it consider the distance between the nodes to find closest possible, or it just takes some random nodes? In other words, are neighbors in bitcoin network, close to each other or they are usually departed from each other by many hops?